Is there a way to express this TypeScript type guard, that involves Generics, without getting a "subtype of constraint" error?
I would like to use a Required/Pick Generic combination to define whether a property (name) on Cat/Dog exists. Then, I would like to create a type guard function that determines whether or not a given Cat/Dog has that property.
However, I get the below error on the NamedAnimal in the return type of the function.
Is there a way to express the below concept in TypeScript, of combining a Required/Pick Generic and a type guard, without an error?
Code tried:
export type AugmentedRequired<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = Omit<T, K> &
  Required<Pick<T, K>>;

type Cat = { name?: boolean };
type Dog = { name?: boolean };

type Animal = Cat | Dog;

type NamedAnimal<T extends Animal = Animal> = AugmentedRequired<T, 'name'>;

export function isNamedAnimal<T extends Animal = Animal>(animal: T): animal is NamedAnimal<T> { // Error is on NamedAnimal<T> in this line
     return 'name' in animal;
}

Error on this code:
A type predicate's type must be assignable to its parameter's type.
  Type 'NamedAnimal<T>' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'NamedAnimal<T>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Animal'.

If this is a known unsupported concept, is there a clean-ish way to suppress the error?
Additional note:
One way that I have found to do this is to use a plain inline function that does not have the type-checking of a type guard, like below. But it seems like I should be able to explicitly define this concept.
export const isNamedAnimal = (animal: Animal) => 'name' in animal;


The purpose of a type guard is to take a wide type and narrow it down. That's what the compiler error means: the result type (narrow) has to be assignable to the argument type (wide). The compiler can't prove in this case that NamedAnimal<T> is narrower subset of T itself.

@JaredSmith One could do this right: animal is Extract<NamedAnimal<T>, T> ?

TS can't predict the result of surgery on generic types with Omit and Pick, see ms/TS#28884. You can suppress the error with Extract or intersections, but in this case I'd say there's no reason to Omit here, since {name?: boolean} & {name: boolean} is equivalent to {name: boolean}, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

I didn't know about Extract, so that is interesting to me! @jcalz, you are absolutely correct that using T instead of Omit<T, K> is the simplest way to solve this, as it gets rid of the error while keeping the same intent. I will put the updated code below. Thank you!

@jcalz Ah, I see that you volunteered to write the answer yourself! You can do that and I will yours and delete mine; apologies for taking so long to get back to this!

In order for a type predicate of the form t is U to be allowed as a return type, TypeScript must be able to see that U is assignable to typeof t to start with. That is, U must be considered a narrowing of t, or that U extends typeof T. If Type is some unrelated type, or a wider type, or a type that's too complicated for TypeScript to see as narrower, then you'll get an error.
You have a generic type T, and are hoping that TypeScript will see Omit<T, "name"> & Required<Pick<T, "name">> is a narrowing of T. This doesn't happen. The Omit utility type is implemented in terms of the Exclude utility type, which is implemented as a conditional type. And while TypeScript can evaluate Omit<T, "name"> for any specific T, it cannot do so for generic T. If T is generic, TypeScript just leaves Omit<T, "name"> effectively unevaluated. It is deferred.  Your intent was that Omit<T, "name"> & Required<Pick<T, "name">> is performing a sort of "surgery" on T that, when the surgery is over, results in something assignable to T. But TypeScript cannot see that intent.  This is considered a missing feature of TypeScript, described at microsoft/TypeScript#28884. Maybe some future version of TypeScript will support this, but right now, it doesn't happen. So you get that error.
Whenever you have a situation where TypeScript fails to see that U extends T but you're sure it does, you can usually replace U with something that TypeScript does see as extending T, and which will evaluate to U if you are correct.  For example, the intersection T & U is definitely assignable to T. And if U extends T is true, then T & U should be equivalent to U.  Or you could use the Extract utility type, like Extract<U, T>. So you can get your existing code to compile if you change it to
declare function isNamedAnimal<T extends Animal>(
    animal: T): animal is T & NamedAnimal<T>; // okay

or
declare function isNamedAnimal<T extends Animal>(
    animal: T): animal is Extract<NamedAnimal<T>, T>; // okay

But in your case, you really don't need to go through this trouble, because there's no real need to use Omit in the first place. The type T & Required<Pick<T, "name">> is effectively identical to Omit<T, "name"> & Required<Pick<T, "name">>. The intersection of a required property and an optional property is a required property, so there's no reason to remove a possibly-optional property before the intersection.  Indeed, T & NamedAnimal<T> that makes things work above can be seen as T & Omit<T, "name"> & Required<Pick<T, "name">> and if that's identical to NamedAnimal<T>, then you can just use that, and Omit<T, "name"> is absorbed by the intersection.
Therefore, you can change your code to this:
type AugmentedRequired<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = 
  T & Required<Pick<T, K>>;

And your original code works as-is:
declare function isNamedAnimal<T extends Animal>(
    animal: T): animal is NamedAnimal<T>; // okay

Playground link to code

This is exactly what the issue was! Thank you for the further explanation. When you said "Your intent was ... performing a sort of "surgery" on T that, when the surgery is over, results in something assignable to T. But TypeScript cannot see that intent," that is a great summary of my intent and why I was frustrated with this. I'm using your suggested code now, and it works perfectly!

Thanks to the comments above, especially the one from @jcalz, I've simplified my code by removing Omit<T, K> in favor of just T. This gets rid of the error while keeping the same intent.
export type AugmentedRequired<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = T &
  Required<Pick<T, K>>;

type Cat = { name?: boolean };
type Dog = { name?: boolean };

type Animal = Cat | Dog;

type NamedAnimal<T extends Animal = Animal> = AugmentedRequired<T, 'name'>;

export function isNamedAnimal<T extends Animal = Animal>(animal: T): animal is NamedAnimal<T> {
  // Error is on NamedAnimal<T> in this line
  return 'name' in animal;
}

